# Why Docker containers can't communicate with each other?

Tags: linux, routes, docker, ip, containers

I have created a small [project](https://github.com/ryan-ju/phusion-baseimage-test) to test Docker clustering.  Basically, the cluster.sh script launches three identical containers, and uses [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) to configure a bridge (`bridge1`) on the host and add an NIC (`eth1`) to each container.

If I log into one of the containers, I can `arping` other containers:

```
# 172.17.99.1
root@d01eb56fce52:/# arping 172.17.99.2
ARPING 172.17.99.2
42 bytes from aa:b3:98:92:0b:08 (172.17.99.2): index=0 time=1.001 sec
42 bytes from aa:b3:98:92:0b:08 (172.17.99.2): index=1 time=1.001 sec
42 bytes from aa:b3:98:92:0b:08 (172.17.99.2): index=2 time=1.001 sec
42 bytes from aa:b3:98:92:0b:08 (172.17.99.2): index=3 time=1.001 sec
^C
--- 172.17.99.2 statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 packets received,  20% unanswered (0 extra)
```

So it seems packets can go through `bridge1`.

**But the problem is I can't `ping` other containers, neither can I send any IP packets through via any tools like `telnet` or `netcat`.**

In contrast, the bridge `docker0` and NIC `eth0` work correctly in all containers.

Here's my route table

```
# 172.17.99.1
root@d01eb56fce52:/# ip route
default via 172.17.42.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.17 
172.17.99.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.99.1
```

and bridge config

```
# host
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
bridge1     8000.8a6b21e27ae6   no      veth1pl25432
                                        veth1pl25587
                                        veth1pl25753
docker0     8000.56847afe9799   no      veth7c87801
                                        veth953a086
                                        vethe575fe2

# host
$ brctl showmacs bridge1
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 8a:6b:21:e2:7a:e6   yes        0.00
  2 8a:a3:b8:90:f3:52   yes        0.00
  3 f6:0c:c4:3d:f5:b2   yes        0.00

# host
$ ifconfig
bridge1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8a:6b:21:e2:7a:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::48e9:e3ff:fedb:a1b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8844 (8.8 KB)  TX bytes:12833 (12.8 KB)

# I'm showing only one veth here for simplicity
veth1pl25432 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8a:6b:21:e2:7a:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::886b:21ff:fee2:7ae6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12366 (12.3 KB)  TX bytes:23180 (23.1 KB)

...
```

and IP FORWARD chain

```
# host
$ sudo iptables -x -v --line-numbers -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 10675 packets, 640500 bytes)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1       15018 22400195 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
2       15007 22399271 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        8160   445331 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
4          11      924 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere            
5          56     4704 ACCEPT     all  --  bridge1 bridge1  anywhere             anywhere
```

Note the pkts cound for rule 5 isn't 0, which means `ping` has been routed correctly (FORWARD chain is executed after routing right?), but somehow didn't reach the destination.

I'm out of ideas why `docker0` and `bridge1` behave differently.  Any suggestion?

**Update 1**

Here's the `tcpdump` output on the target container when pinged from another.

```
$ tcpdump -i eth1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
22:11:17.754261 IP 192.168.1.65 > 172.17.99.1: ICMP echo request, id 26443, seq 1, length 6
```

Note the source IP is `192.168.1.65`, which is the `eth0` of the host, so there seems to be some SNAT going on on the bridge.

Finally, printing out the `nat` IP table revealed the cause of the problem:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
...
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
...
```

Because my container's `eth0`'s IP is on `172.17.0.0/16`, packets sent have their source IP changed.  This is why the responses from `ping` can't go back to the source.

**Conclusion**

The solution is to change the container's `eth0`'s IP to a different network than that of the default `docker0`.

Comment: I'm trying to `ping` from one container to another container, not from host to container.  As such, I didn't assign an IP to `bridge1` on the host.

Comment: you shoudl have a look at this article "sending signals from one container to another"   http://blog.dixo.net/2015/02/sending-signals-from-one-docker-container-to-another/

Comment: Well, it turns out the key was to actually assign an IP in the same network to `bridge1`.  I thought this was unnecessary, but it solved the problem.  If anyone knows why please do tell me.

Comment: Here's a similar question, http://superuser.com/q/916368/201625

Comment: I have solved the problem.  Please see the updates.

Comment: If you've found the solution, you should post it as the answer and accept it. So it's documented and others can clearly see the solution.

Comment: @user3452275 thanks, I've added my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copied from `Update 1` in question

Here's the `tcpdump` output on the target container when pinged from another.

```
$ tcpdump -i eth1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
22:11:17.754261 IP 192.168.1.65 > 172.17.99.1: ICMP echo request, id 26443, seq 1, length 6
```

Note the source IP is `192.168.1.65`, which is the `eth0` of the host, so there seems to be some SNAT going on on the bridge.

Finally, printing out the `nat` IP table revealed the cause of the problem:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
...
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere
...
```

Because my container's `eth0`'s IP is on `172.17.0.0/16`, packets sent have their source IP changed.  This is why the responses from `ping` can't go back to the source.

**Conclusion**

The solution is to change the container's `eth0`'s IP to a different network than that of the default `docker0`.